# Magento Customer Update API Error - Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: api, magento, stdclass

Hi Im am trying to connect to magento api Customer Update using SOAP UI. I perfectly connect and update products. I can list Customers 
but for some reason I can not update a customer. The xml I am using is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:customerCustomerUpdateRequestParam>
         <sessionId>65e47ee067bba9c51b97c8d80929a138</sessionId>
         <customerId>1</customerId>
         <customerData>
            <email>33@ddd.com</email>
         </customerData>
      </urn:customerCustomerUpdateRequestParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the response I get is the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Cannot use object of type stdClass as array</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can any one shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check your Magento log files, there's probably a stack trace that goes with that error and it'd be useful to post it here.

Comment: Heres the response in the error.log  -------- 2016/05/20 09:53:34 [error] 2725#0: *53 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /mnt/hgfs/nnn/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php on line 49" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.1.2.69, server: vvv.vm, request: "POST /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "nnn.vm"

Comment: Found the culprit. A third party extension was overriding the customer api.